# rsync as a background process?

Tags: linux, rsync

I've been using rsync to sync a bunch of files between my two servers. I set a cron job that would run rsync every minute. However, I'd prefer if I could have it run always, so that files are synced the moment they are changed. What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have inotify in your kernel, check out [inotify-tools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/).

There's an example on that page:

```
#!/bin/sh
# A slightly complex but actually useful example
inotifywait -mrq --timefmt '%d/%m/%y %H:%M' --format '%T %f' \
 -e close_write /home/billy | while read date time file; do
    rsync /home/billy/${file} rsync://billy@example.com/backup/${file} && \
    echo "At ${time} on ${date}, file ${file} was backed up via rsync"
done
```

Comment: I'm interested in this solution @Doug. Would you mind explaining what the different parts of this script do?

Comment: FWIW (four years later), `lsyncd` is a daemon-like program that wraps up this functionality in a very elegant and fairly cross-platform way: https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/

Answer (score 1):

use the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) system of linux, in combination with [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en).

Comment: Doug Harris has a nice example usage.  Care to further document yours as well?

Comment: doug copyNpasted the sample direct from that page :) to avoid doing the same: http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=doc&lang=en
(rtfm) ... it works just like cron, just in a different directory (/etc/incron.d/)