# Linux: Create mirror of directory, but ignore deletions

Tags: linux, file-management

I would like to create a directory `public_html/archive` that is a mirror of `public_html/images`, *except* that deletions in the `images` directory don't cause corresponding deletions in `archive`.

I was going to manage all of this in code, but then I figured, maybe the system can handle it for me in a robust way.

Note that the website will reference `archive` in real time, so it has to be an instant mirror and not something done nightly, etc.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Are all the new images created by a single program or script? If so, modifying that code to write to both places might be the easiest solution.

Comment: This is probably the best solution for most people. :) However, 1) I am curious, and 2) The "script" is a CMS, so the event "file is being saved" is a little less straightforward and requires making sure all the right hooks are attended to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) or [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) might work if you didn't need it realtime. A realtime solution would end up being somewhat like [sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org/) - using inotify to check for changes, and copying changed files somewhere.

Comment: Accepted for mentioning inotify, which led me here: http://superuser.com/questions/46441/rsync-as-a-background-process which mentions inotify-tools. Thanks!

Comment: yay for the scattergun approach. amusingly this might help solve a project i was plotting myself, which would involve inotify

Answer (score 0):

Using xcopy 's /D switch you can specify only files after [the day/time of last back up]. It sounds like you don't need to mirror so much as push new files into the archive.

For Linux, per the tag, you can run a `find` for files after [the day/time of last back up], the `cp` them to the destination directory (with  something like `$ find . \! -cnewer date_marker`). You can dig into `rsync` and use the exclude tag for it as well, that might afford you more flexibility with directories.

Comment: Local rsync looks close to what I want, except that I want the syncing to happen automatically without invoking a command. As soon as my app creates a file in "images", I want it to create one in "archive". Like a symlink except the target ignores deletions in the source.

Comment: Hm. I know you can use `cron` to run it hourly or whatever... but I'm guessing you want instantaneous hence why you said mirroring.