# How to move a file of 250 GB to another server?

Tags: centos, wget, tar

The hard disk of one of my servers is full, so I need to move a file away from it to make room.

I have tried `tar -cvf` but when I send it to the other server using `wget -c`, I see it is 100% complete. The problem is that the size of the file is different even though it reported being finished.

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are asking. Could you clarify?

Comment: i want backup file in server to another server

Comment: Do you first create the tarball and then download it? What do you mean with 'file not finish'?

Comment: create a tarball and use rsync, in my experience, wget isn't good for big files, usually they are corrupted.

Comment: what tarball ? how to use rsync ? i am first time

Comment: @monkey_boys i posted an answer, but please try to do a simple search before you ask, these kind of question tend to be voted down or closed for obvious reasons. If you do a search, and still unable to find an answer, then say why you need help, and everyone will help you gladly, there many tutorials out there on how to create a tar and how to use rsync, you could even search superuser - next time when you reply to someone who commented on your question, use `@`, to reply to me `@Fischer` so i can be notified that you replied to me, otherwise I may never reply to you.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exact commands did you use (on which machine) to create the tar file? What `wget` command did you use? If @Fischer's suggestions don't get you far, please [edit] your post with your attempts and where you got stuck. Also, have a look at how to properly format posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

next time when you reply to someone who commented on your question, use `@`, to reply to me `@Fischer` so i can be notified that you replied to me, otherwise I may never reply to you.

I'll link to some tutorials.

To [create a tarball](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-a-tar-file-linux-command-line/)

you go to the file location using `cd`, then you do

```
tar -cvf example.tar /example
```

Then [to use rsync](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html) on a RedHat-based distribution

```
yum install rsync
```

or, if you are on Debian-based distribution

```
apt-get install rsync
```

then transfer to the new server

```
rsync -av -e ssh username@oldserverip:/path/to/example.tar /example.tar
```

(note that you have the option to gzip the file on-the-fly by adding the `-z` flag)

and at last `untar` on the new server, go to where the `tar` is located, use `ls` to help you see the file.

```
tar -xvf example.tar
```

Comment: user rsync command in newserver ?

Comment: @monkey_boys yes, in the command shown above, you need to install rsync on new server, and use rsync on new server, use the old server ip addresss, however if you want to install rsync on the old server and copy from it to new server, you'd use `rsync -av -e example.tar username@newserveripaddress:~/location/where/you/want/to/transfer`

Comment: please see the links i gave you: **Task : Copy file from a local computer to a remote server**

Comment: now i can use, how to run in background mode  that ask password and stuck

Comment: @monkey_boys I didn't understand the question? what is the problem?

Comment: how to run rsync  in background mode

Comment: @monkey_boys please read this http://superuser.com/questions/46441/rsync-as-a-background-process